# Full text search in multiple columns with PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search

I just started using postgreSQL for fuzzy text matching. I have two columns: `job_title` and `company_name`.

A typical full text search would concatenate `job_title` and `company_name`, then return search text result according to a single ranking.

However, treating text match in two columns equally can be problematic in my case. For example, `Search Engineer` at `Google Co.` should not be ranked equally with `Google Search` at `Engineer Co.`

I know that I can assign different weights for each column. However, I don't have a reason to weight one more important than other.

How do I match my keywords against each of the columns separately, and return some "match score" on each keywords?

Something like:

```
Jobs.where("(to_tsvector('english', position) @@ plainto_tsquery(:q)) AND 

(to_tsvector('english',company) @@ plainto_tsquery(:q))", q: "Search Engineer", q: "Google")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've pointed out, you can concatenate tsvectors:

```
# select to_tsvector('job description') ||
         to_tsvector('company as keyword') ||
         to_tsvector('job description as body') as vector;
                          vector                           
-----------------------------------------------------------
 'bodi':9 'compani':3 'descript':2,7 'job':1,6 'keyword':5
(1 row)
```

And you can also assign them weights:

```
# select (setweight(to_tsvector('job description'), 'A') ||
         setweight(to_tsvector('company as keyword'), 'B') ||
         setweight(to_tsvector('job description as body'), 'D')) as vector;
                            vector                             
---------------------------------------------------------------
 'bodi':9 'compani':3B 'descript':2A,7 'job':1A,6 'keyword':5B
(1 row)
```

You can also play around with `ts_rank_cd()`. In particular, you could change the way the scores are normalized.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html

In your case, it seems that you want to combine two separate queries instead. An ugly but possibly adequate solution might look like this:

```
select sum(rank) as rank, ...
from (
   select ...
   union all
   select ...
   ) as sub
group by ...
order by sum(rank) desc
limit 10
```

As you can see, it's not very pretty. It's also a boulevard for aggregating potentially large sets of matching rows. Imho, you'll be better off sticking with the built-in tsvector arithmetic and tweaking weights if needed.